# GridLayoutManager does not support stack from end. Consider using reverse layout

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

Iam trying to Add new items to top of RecyclerView but the scroll  stack at bottom

i need solution please

this is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    manager.setReverseLayout(true);

    Recycler.setLayoutManager(manager );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`setStackFromEnd`** is not possible in GridLayoutManager. Hence you will have to reverse the data in your list. This means you will need to reverse the entire order of your list. If you are appending items meant to show up at the bottom, you will have to insert them at the beginning instead.

```
 Collections.reverse(yourList);
```

Comment: This is one of the best answer ever. Thank you so much for saving my time.